# Xarray: Setting common name for two coordinates which physically belong to the same dimension

Tags: python, python-xarray

Sorry in advance for the unhelpful title, but I couldn't come up with a good short description of what I'm asking.

It's common for data in fluid dynamics applications to have coordinates of the following way:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 4, yC: 5, yF: 5)
Coordinates:
  * yF       (yF) float64 0.0 0.4883 0.9766 1.465 1.953
  * yC       (yC) float64 0.2441 0.7324 1.221 1.709 2.197
  * time     (time) float64 0.1146 1.031 1.948 2.406
Data variables:
    ω_x      (time, yF) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(4, 5), meta=np.ndarray>
    w        (time, yC) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(4, 5), meta=np.ndarray>
```

Note that two of the dimensions (`yC` and `yF`) have staggered values. This is because they are both values of the physical dimension `y`. They are, however, staggered just like the figure below (taken from the `xgcm` package docs):

[image]

Is there any way to tell `xarray` that these two dimensions are actually the same? So that I could possibly do

```
ds.ω_x.plot(y='y') # instead of ds.ω_x.plot(y='yF')
ds.w.plot(y='y') # instead of ds.w.plot(y='yC')
```

and it would work as expected?